# margin auto not working when using col-lg-8 bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to build a Webshop.

Now I am trying to place an extra `div` in the main container. To center it I have made a class for auto margin. The problem is that it is not working with Bootstrap's `col-lg-8`. I have colored the background black to see what happens. It is aligned left. If I give a fixed width to the `div` it will align it in the center but the `background-color` is not showing due to the height of the `div` that turned to `0px`.

Why is margin auto not working when I use Bootstrap `col-lg-8`? And why is the height gone of my `div` when I give it a fixed width. I have had the problem before that when I used and auto height, the height of the `div` gets a value of 0 even when there is a form in it with inputs. I wanted it to scale to the content.

```
<body>
    <div id="container" class="container col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-8 margin-auto" style="background-color: #000;">
            <form class="col-lg-12">
                <input type="submit" value="Bestellen" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: where is the `row` ?

Comment: Why `container col-lg-12 `for same div ?

Comment: `<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2"` margin auto doesn't work because cols in Bootstrap 3 float left.

Comment: what bootstrap version are using ? V3 or V4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a) a `row` and b) give your `col-lg-8` an offset of 2. `margin-auto` doesn't work on floating elements (which is how Bootstrap 3 does `col` elements).

```
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="background-color: #000;">
      <form class="col-lg-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Bestellen" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Elements that contain only floating elements have `height: 0;` per default. To make sure you have the container element visually contain its children, you need to add `clearfix` class to the container.

Comment: someone edited the question to include bootstrap V3 ... but the OP never specified which version, so we need to verify this as am pretty sure he's using the V4

Comment: col classes are named differently in V4. It has to be 3.

Comment: no they are the same, the classes he used are also provided in the V4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: V4 uses `mx-auto` whereas V3 uses `margin-auto`.

Comment: how do i get the second div to be centered and not take the full witdh without hardcoding the width?

Comment: Oh i needed a hard refresh